# Is it possible to use more than one Ad networks in my mobile game to boost fill rate?

Tags: ads

If I can install more than one video ad sdk to enhance the fill rate. Is it possible?

Thanks,
Karthick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible and I would advise to do so. There are different monetization platforms (I tried MobFox, Startapp, now i'm using Appodeal) and the idea is quite simple, you get access to several ad networks using one SDK, this way the app gets maximal revenue from ads. Would recommend Appodeal, because they support all major ad networks and have flexible payouts. My android casual game has video ads and interstitials, it's average eCPM with Appodeal is average eCPM was 5.6$ for interstitials; 7$ video in august.

Comment: Thank you John Bolino.
I did my search and found the existance of Google ad exchange and OpenX. :)